# Jquery fail display whole content

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Below are my codes :

```
   <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%> data-content=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>>Info</a>

   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        });
```

In my table

`Title : Test test 123`

Description : jquery test

[image]

why my jquery cant display all?only able display first sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing "'" to encapsulate the a tag attribute.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%>' data-content='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>'>Info</a>
```